# how to bind event to ajax appended elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, delegates

I use this code to use a jquery plugin for date picker:

```
    //DatePicker
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".inpDate").datepicker({
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            autoClose: true,
        }
        );
    });
```

But how can I bind datepicker() to elements that appended to form or document?

I used **DOMNodeInserted** but not worked for ajax.

Comment: @Andreas 
 
I don't want to initial datepicker every time I focus on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for dynamic created html try this:

```
$('body').on('focus',".textbox", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});​
```

Comment: I don't want to initial datepicker every time I focus on it.